# Android JSONArrays inside JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, jsonexception

Here's the relevant part of my json file:

```
"categories": [
     [
         "Belgian Restaurant", 
         "belgian"
     ], 
     [
         "Brasserie", 
         "brasseries"
     ]
 ],
```

What i want to do is retrieve informations from the second `JSONArray` (let's say "brasseries" for example).

The following code worked for retrieving informations from the first array:

```
JSONArray categories = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");
restaurant.setCat1(categories.getJSONArray(0).getString(1));
```

The result of this was "belgian" as expected, but then i tryed the same for the second array:

```
restaurant.setCat2(categories.getJSONArray(1).getString(1));
```

and that threw  a `Index 1 out of range [0..1)` JSONException

I don't get it since indexes 0 and 1 clearly exist in the file ... Why would 0 work and not 1 ?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong in code which you have posted. May  be something else is causing the issue.

Comment: I don't know what then, it's the first time i deal with such nested JSONArrays

Comment: I assume there is some context around `"categories"`. Are you sure that you are in the correct `JSONObject` (e.g. have you logged `categories`)?

Comment: I just did and it correctly logs ["Brasserie","brasseries"]

Comment: @clementino36, try this  restaurant.setCat2(categories.getJSONArray(0).getString(1));

Comment: Well no because Cat2 is supposed to be taken from the second array... This will work for sure but it's not the data i wish to retrieve

Comment: @clementino36,  I can  see only one element inside categories array , the first array has a nested array, so that is what you will have to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that there is a array inside another array without a name, your error can be ignored like this,

```
restaurant.setCat2(categories.getJSONArray(0).getString(1));
```

before coding for any `JSON` data, you should always check if it is right,

as `JSON` in the question is lacking the `KEY's` for the different values that you want to iterate,

it would be difficult to get the information if the inner object change it's incessant variables, (any increase or decrease will lead to erroneous result).

try to generate `JSON` with key-value pair,

Example

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "00",
      "name": "Some_name_0"
    },
    {
      "id": "01",
      "name": "Some_name_1"
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "name": "Some_name_2"
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "name": "Some_name_3"
    },
    {
      "id": "04",
      "name": "Some_name_4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I will try that eventhough i don't get why i can Log the data without problem but can't use it. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: @clementino36, you may want to write this restaurant.setCat2(categories.getJSONArray(0).getString(1));

Comment: @clementino36, Thank you, it is appreciated, Good day to you !